# Android Camera Example NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to implement the camera SDK example code from the [Android website](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera), but when I try to run the app I get this Null Pointer Exception and logcat doesn't really give me a whole lot of info to go on. I am pretty new to Android development so I am not sure how to proceed in debugging this issue.

```
06-07 09:48:24.960      927-927/com.luketim.cam.cam2.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.luketim.cam.cam2.app, PID: 927
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.luketim.cam.cam2.app.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:34)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:572)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
            at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:175)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1871)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the class with the method where this NullPointerException is thrown.

```
package com.luketim.cam.cam2.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by luketimothy on 06/06/2014.
 */
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "";
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> logcat doesn't really give me a whole lot of info to go on

It tells you the line of code on which you crashed (`CameraPreview.java:34`, in your `surfaceCreated()` method), and why you crashed (a `NullPointerException occurred on that line)`.

Since there are only two lines in `surfaceCreated()`, it is clear that `mCamera` is `null`. Since that is provided from outside the code that you have listed, you will need to track down where you are opening the camera and determine why that did not work as expected.

FWIW, writing a camera application in Android is rather difficult. It is not something that somebody new to Android should be attempting. I offer [a library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) to try to simplify using the camera from within an app, but even that does not yet handle every oddball thing that device manufacturers do.

Comment: I'm not exactly new to Java, but it's been a couple of years since I last used it. Somehow I managed to miss the line number there! I am new to Android, though. I will check out your Library, it should be a great help for someone like myself. Thanks!

Comment: @Luke: Sorry. Usually, if somebody has difficulty interpreting a stack trace, they are new to Java. I struck the reference to that from my answer.